# Linux Mint 17.1 shutdown option doesn't work

Tags: linux, linux-mint, shutdown

Sometimes when I use the shutdown option in cinnamon the system closes some of the running programs and then just sits on the desktop until I tell it to shutdown again. The shutdown and poweroff commands never have this problem and with the shutdown option it only occurs rarely but primarily seems to occur if I shutdown during disk activity such as a download from steam.

My system just started doing this when I did a reinstall of Linux Mint to switch from a BIOS emulated boot to a native UEFI boot. It's not a huge issue but I would like to be able to tell my system to shut down only once and have it do it. I've taken a look in syslog to see if there's anything weird around shutdowns but there doesn't seem to be.

Comment: This sounds like a cinnamon bug, I've had the same thing. I doubt we'll be able to help you here much, we'll probably have to wait for the devs to fix it.

Comment: @terdon alright. I didn't realize that. I made the post cause for me it didn't start happening till I did a reinstall.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I just know that I've seen that with Cinnamon running on a BIOS system.

Comment: @terdon Well that kinda sucks but I guess there's nothing to be done then.